# Python Array Extra Comma Formatting

Tags: python, arrays

I'm pretty new to Python and I have done some research on this question but I can't seem to find an answer.

I have a select query that sends to an array (**Python 2.7**)

```
query = "SELECT catalog_product_entity.sku "
query = query+"FROM catalog_product_entity "
query = query+"INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal "
query = query+"ON catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id "
query = query+"INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int "
query = query+"ON catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id "
query = query+"WHERE catalog_product_entity.sku IS NOT NULL "
query = query+"AND catalog_product_entity_int.attribute_id = '84'"
x = myconn.cursor()
x.execute(query)
skuArray = x.fetchall()
for i in skuArray:
    print i
```

The query works sucessfully but displays as: `('000381001238',),`

How can I format the array to display as `('000381001238'),`?

I have also tried this:

```
for i in skuArray:
    prodSku = [i[0] for  in x.fetchall()]
    print prodSku
```

Side note for performance, This query has over 8000 unique values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns a *list of rows* which, if a default cursor is used, are *represented by tuples*. If you have a single column in the select statement, simply get it by index:

```
for row in x.fetchall():
    print(row[0])
```

Or, if you need to collect the column values in a list:

```
sku_values = [row[0] for row in x.fetchall()]
```

As a side note, you don't have to concatenate parts of the query with `+=` - you can use Python's *multiline strings* where, as a bonus, you'll be able to indent your query properly that will improve readability:

```
query = """
    SELECT catalog_product_entity.sku
    FROM catalog_product_entity
        INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal ON catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id
            INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int ON catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id 
    WHERE catalog_product_entity.sku IS NOT NULL 
          AND catalog_product_entity_int.attribute_id = '84'
"""
```

Comment: Thank you! Side note for anyone in the future using this wanting to append it to an array: `results = x.fetchall()
skuArray = []
for i in results:
    skuArray.append(i[0])
print skuArray`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `fetchall()` is returning a tuple:

try:

```
for i in skuArray:
    print i[0]
```

to only get the first element of the tuple.